I'd look at you till I [was/would be] blind
I am wondering how the meaning would change in this sentence:

If I could hold you one more time
Like in the days when you were mine
I'd look at you till I was blind
So you would stay.

if we replaced 'I was blind' with 'I would be blind'.
(from 'One more time' by Richard Marx)

It wouldn't 'change the meaning', it would simply be ungrammatical.

Focusing on the independent clause of the conditional, rewritten as "I would look 'til I lost my sight" it may seem strange to use past simple ie 'was blind', 'lost'. But the loss must have happened for them to stop looking.
Avoid analaysing lyrics and poetry, they have license to break rules and are best simply appreciated.
